# Proofs Involving Disjunctions: Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I want to focus on Exercise 4 of Section 3.5 of Velleman's book. I am aware of the other questions that have been asked, so this one is not a duplicate. I would like to discuss a little more considering the answer that was given in:
[For all sets $A$, $B$, and $C$, if $A \cap C \subseteq B \cap C$ and $A \cup C \subseteq B \cup C$, then $A \subseteq B$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2868472/for-all-sets-a-b-and-c-if-a-cap-c-subseteq-b-cap-c-and-a-cup-c?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Suppose $A\cap C \subseteq B\cap C$ and $A \cup C \subseteq B\cup C$. Prove that $A \subseteq B$.

So the assumptions are clear: $x \in A$, $A\cap B \subseteq B\cap C$, and $A \cup C \subseteq B\cup C$. My question is on the following reasoning: Since $x\in A$ and $A \cup C \subseteq B\cup C$, we conclude that $x\in B\cup C$, so our cases to analyze would be $x\in B$ and $x\in C$, instead of $x\in C$ and $x\notin C$ as suggested in the question I quoted earlier. Is my reasoning correct? Ohterwise, I would like to know if there is some special reason why the $x\in C$ and $x\notin C$ cases could be the preferred path to follow.

Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thanks, just corrected it

Answer (score 1):

You can start by observing that if $x\in A$, then $x\in A\cup C\subseteq B\cup C$, but that does not force you to split the rest of the argument into cases $x\in B$ and $x\in C$: there is a perfectly good continuation that starts by splitting it into cases $x\in C$ and $x\notin C$. That argument goes as follows:

> If $x\notin C$, then clearly $x\in B$, and we’re done. If $x\in C$, then $x\in A\cap C$, so $x\in B\cap C$, so $x\in B$.

Splitting it your way leads to essentially the same argument:

> If $x\in B$, we’re done. If $x\in C$, then $x\in A\cap C$, so $x\in B\cap C$, so $x\in B$.

It’s pretty much six of one and half a dozen of the other.